# Не подключаются стили для IE, заключённые в условные комментарии

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

Прописал параметры у некоторых классов под IE в отдельном файле, файл подключаю так:

```
<!--[if IE]><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/ie.css"><![endif]-->
```

Но IE всё равно цепляет стили классов из файла, который подключается раньше. Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Условные комментарии — фирменная фишка IE — не работают в IE10+. Начиная с этой версии, Майкрософт объявил, что их браузер нормально поддерживает стандарты, не содержит хитрых вендорных фич, и корявые хаки под конкретный браузер должны умереть. Пользуйтесь теми же методами, что и для остальных браузеров: проверяйте поддержку фич, а не версию браузера.

В более старых версиях IE и в режимых совместимости с этими версиями условные комментарии продолжают работать.

Comment: Athari, спасибо! IE 10 не поддерживает Flexbox. Из-за этого ломается дизайн футера, flex распределяет пять колонок равномерно по ширине, а в ie они все съезжают влево без отступов. Такая беда!